# Beautiful Soup - Accessing Text on a Changing Class Name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i've been at this for hours and i've been close several times.

What i'm trying to achieve:

- Scrape an address website to return all street names in an area.
- Have a list of street names without any additional code or text.

I can't seem to get the correct combination of find/find_all/select/get_text usage.

Code so far, i've been through many different variations.

```
import requests
import bs4

site = requests.get(
    'https://www.streetlist.co.uk/towns/greater-london/peckham')

status = site.status_code
print(status)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(site.text, 'html.parser')


soup2 = soup.select('div', class_='searchcontainer')

for item in soup2:
    soup3.append(item)

print(soup3)
```

This returns the street names but also the surrounding 'a href' info. I think the issue may lie on that the class name changes depending on the first letter of the street name it is displaying.

All and any help appreciated

Comment: r = [i.text.strip() for i in soup2.select('.searchcontainer .btn')]

Comment: Thank you, i used the additional .btn selector to narrow down the results and used .text.strip() to get the correct results!

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the text using `.text` property:

```
for item in soup2:
    soup3.append(item.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you, that got me closer. My result is now returned without comma separations and with \n\t randomly spread throughout the text. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Edited please check

Answer (score 0):

I used the comments from Wasif Hasan and QHarr to arrive at this and it worked:

```
import requests
import bs4

site = requests.get(
    'https://www.streetlist.co.uk/towns/greater-london/mayfair')

status = site.status_code
print(status)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(site.text, 'html.parser')


soup2 = soup.select('.searchcontainer .btn')

soup3 = []

for item in soup2:
    soup3.append(item.text.strip())

print(soup3)
```

Full list of street names from the postcode area, all in a list with comma separation.